# How does COM client code refer to the IID in the type library?

Tags: visual-c++, com

Compiling a COM client of which the source code contains a line like

```
#import "../server/IFoo.tlb"
```

generates ifoo.tlh in the current working directory.

In ifoo.tlh, there are IIDs in string form wrapped by function (or function-like macros) calls, e.g. `uuid("6bee2d26-f3d8-11d4-825d-00104b3646c0")`, which means the .tlh file definitely knows the values of the IIDs. The question is that in client codes how can I refer to those IIDs without `#include` any header file of the COM server? In the .tlh file or the .tlb file, are there any (compiled) symbols that represent the IIDs that we can use in the client codes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [__uuidof operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/uuidof-operator?view=msvc-160) (Microsoft Specific):

> Retrieves the GUID attached to the expression.
>
> Syntax
>
> __uuidof ( expression )